# Doctrine2 mapping an array of ID's rather than entities

Tags: doctrine-orm

Is it possible to create a mapping from one entity A to entity B but instead just store an array within entity A which contains only the ID's of related entity B.

```
class A
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @var int[]    One to many relationship which only has the ID's of class B
     */
    private $bIds;

    ...
}

class B
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @var A    Many to one relationship
     */
    private $a;
}
```

Comment: You would still need to load those related entities. So why not just have a helper method on `A` that returns the ids as an array?

Comment: Apparently not. Had a chat on the irc channels and it seems I can pull it off with a custom repo/hydrator combination.

Comment: Well even that isn't a full solution since the entity manager won't know how to persist the relationship. Apparently, it's just a limitation of doctrine at the moment http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html